# how to create a global app bar in windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

my app is includes many web views and I want to create a global app bar appear in each web view in the app .I haven't any code for this .
help please !!

Comment: Did you try anything? Is this for a windows store application?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541674/global-app-bar-on-windows-8-application

Answer (score 0):

Make an appbar for the mainpage

Then, when switching between xaml pages, do 
`this.Content = new Page().Content; //change page to the page you want it to switch to.`

To switch back to the first page, first add this in an initialize event.

```
UIElement main;
main = this.Content;
```